# Python Exception not Raised

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, subprocess

I am working with a python gui application which I forked, modified, and am now debugging (for a custom game controller, if you must know). The application launches a subprocess to handle communication with an arduino, which subprocess launches various functions to handle particular operations. I'm trying to build in a TimeoutError exception in to a particular function to give me more information about a process that the arduino does not respond to, but exceptions do not appear to be getting raised/handled appropriately (read: I don't know how to do it). This is the call to the function (still within the subprocess):

```
# STATE = Perform CNIA
if n_program_state == 4:
    mQ.put((0, 'Starting CNIA...'))
    try:
        cnia(ser, conn, vessel) #This is the function that should raise the TimeoutError
    except TimeoutError:
        mq.put((1,'exception raised'))
        mq.put((1, ' '.join(err.args)))
        time.sleep(5)
        pass
    mQ.put((0, 'CNIA Complete'))
    n_program_state = 5
```

These are the first few lines of the cnia function, which I have added a fake timeouterror to:

```
def cnia(ser, conn, vessel):
    f_cnia_repeat = True
    raise TimeoutError("clnr: fake timeout2")
    ...
```

When I run the program and trigger the subprocess, the message queue goes as far as "Starting CNIA" and then the subprocess hangs. I would expect it to raise the exception and then print the error message I've specified - what am I missing? Apologies for kludgy code, original author claimed non-expertise, and I'm likely even worse.

Comment: The full repo is at https://github.com/mrpeverill/KerbalKockpit

Comment: The entire purpose of `cnia` is to set an undefined variable to `True` and raise an exception?  Mind if I ask why?  Seems like the long way around the barn to some unknown destination.

Comment: is it not because you went from mQ.put (upper Q) to mq.put (lower q)?

Comment: There is a lot more to the CNIA function, I am just am testing it with a fake exception to see if I can get it to raise before it does anything else.

I'd be lying if I said I fully understood the message queue, but changing the queue to 0 in the catch statement makes no change.

Answer (score -1):

I don't really understand your code but what I can interpret here is that, you didn't even reach into the `cnia` function. Try to add a `print` before `f_cnia_repeat = True` and see if it is invoked

Comment: print doesn't seem to do anything - maybe because it's a subprocess?

Answer (score -1):

err.args is probably creating an unhandled exception.
Try to add err object: `except TimeoutError as err:`